# Mat-Dialog Passing Array and Populate It Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So here is my question I will input a value in the QTY text field. Mat dialog will pop up that shows the number of quantities that I inputted. How do you iterate an object/data in afterclosed? and populate it to the `setItem?` I get the result, but it won't iterate it pass to the `setItem` how to do it? this is what I did so far

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-2akxdg

updated: i can get the qty, but i can't get what i input in mat-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are not sending your data from `mat-dialog` when it is closed.

in the `alter-dialog.component.ts` file you're just sending qty on `save()`

```js
//your method which is not sending the required data
save() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.data.qty);
  }
```

you need to send your inputted data too, like this

```js
//save method that is returning required data
save() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.fg.value);
    //fg is your form, it has qty too, so no need to send qty separately
  }
```

in `app.component.ts` you need to iterate properly `afterclose`, `result` itself is not an array, actually, it is an object. `displayArray` is the actual array that is present in the `result` object. you need to iterate like this

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('qty' + result.qty);
      for (let i = 0; i < result.displayArray.length; i++) {
        this.setItem.push(this.CreatesetItem(result.displayArray[i].MoreItem));
      }
    });
```

[click here to see Stackblitz example with your expected answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-x4e1is?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('qty' + result.qty);
      for (let i = 0; i < result.displayArray.length; i++) {
        this.setItem.push(this.CreatesetItem(result.displayArray[i].MoreItem));
      }
    });
this is where im very confused thank you